# change commuinty name snmp via zpl commande

Tags: command-line, ftp, snmp, zebra-printer

I want to change the community name snmp for zebra printer via `zpl commands` the community name snmp is `public` in default, i tried with `^NN command` , but nothing change, this is an example :

```
^XA

^NN,,,loreal,loreal,loreal

^XZ
```

I wrote this command in file test.zpl, and I send it to the printer via FTP

Any idea ??!

NOTE : `^NN – Set SNMP`

Use this command to set the Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) parameters.

```
Format: ^NNa,b,c,d,e,f
```

Parameters Details

```
a = system name Same as printer name.

b = system contact Any contact information as desired (such as a name or phrase)

c = system location The printer’s model information.

d = get community name,  Default: public

e = set community name Values: Up to 19 alphanumeric characters, Default: public

f = trap community name Values: Up to 20 alphanumeric characters, Default: public
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi all I found the solution for this issue :

**first** I create file with `ZPL II` commands `test.zpl` inside the file I wrote this command :

```
^XA 
^NN,,,test,test,test
^XZ
```

**seconde** I contact with printer and send this file to the printer via `FTP` with command line :

```
c:> put c:\test.zpl
```

**third** I restart the printer with sending `~JR` command, and I walk the `MIB tree`.

```
snmpwalk -v1 -c TEST "address IP" enterprises.10642.20.10.10.5
```